# Подскажите, как можно оптимизировать загрузку сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я сделал сайт, залил на демо-хостинг, вот его адрес: 
win2020.000webhostapp.com
В чем же его проблема? Дело в том, что когда сайт загружается, лоадер очень тормозит. Также при появлении основного контента происходят пролагивания. Подскажите, как можно оптимизировать код?

P. S  Ещё одна проблема: после загрузки сайта, замечаю что браузер занимает намного больше оперативной памяти(!400 мб!), чем обычно(50-100мб)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может-быть дело не в сайте, а в каких-то плагинах/браузере который вы используете?

Потыкал сейчас с компа, всё плавно и ест страничка не больше остальных в Windows Chrome

Comment: Да, действительно на мощных устройствах всё прекрасно работает. Но на слабом телефоне всё очень плохо. И да, я всё же решил проблему. Дело было в лоадере, который был очень тяжёлым для слабых устройств. Я просто заменил его на более простой.

Comment: По мне так всё очень быстро загружается

Answer (score 0):

Может и в сайте есть проблемы, но не только. Хостинг который вы используйте бесплатный и было ожидаемо что владельцы хостинга будут ограничивать скорость. Я когда-то тоже использовал этот хостинг и с ним всегда проблемы были - низкая скорость, частые вылеты, иногда вообще остановка.